# What does this "no switchport" command do?

Tags: layer2

I came across this command at a Layer 2 Switch, and I don't know what it does.

```
no switchport
Ip Addr 10.2.3.4 255.255.0.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would have to be commands provided from an interface on a L3 capable switch.

The `no switchport` command puts the interface in L3 mode (known as "routed port") and makes it operate more like a router interface rather than a switch port. The `ip address` command assigns an IP address and network mask to the interface. Routed ports can be configured with a Layer 3 routing protocol.

However, [restrictions apply](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg3750/swint.html#16355):

- It does not support VLAN subinterfaces.
- It does not support Layer 2 protocols, such as DTP and STP.
- It is supported only on switches running the IP base or IP services image.

Comment: Thanks YLearn, When I saw the picture I couldn't imagine which it will be a L3